# How do you run a single capybara test that uses the selenium driver?

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara

There are pleanty of examples where you use rspec, selenium, and capybara to run tests that start like this:

```
it "does something", :js => true do
```

and you can run everything by running "rake spec", but how do you run a single capybara/selenium test? I cannot figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: Have you read [README](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-rspec)?

Answer (score 5):

You can [tag an example](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-12/docs/command-line/tag-option!):

```
it "does something", :js => true, :focus => true do

$ rspec . --tag focus
```

Or you can [specify the line number of the spec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/line-number-appended-to-file-path!):

```
$ rspec my_spec.rb:37
```